# How to install all upgrades (not just security) with puppet's unattended-upgrades module

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I'm using puppet to configure a classroom of desktops running Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm using the puppet [unattended-upgrades](https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/unattended_upgrades) module.

However, I can't tell from the docs (I'm a Linux noob) how to use this to automatically upgrade all packages, not just security.

In the overview of the module it says:

> The unattended_upgrades module allows for the installation and
>   configuration of automatic security (and other) updates through apt.

The "(and other)" seems to indicate it should be able to do this.  How can I use this module to upgrade all installed packages, and not just security updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set "origins". By default it is just security ([see here](https://github.com/hmrc/puppetlabs-apt/blob/master/manifests/unattended_upgrades.pp#L17)).

```
apt::unattended_upgrades {
  origins             => $::apt::params::origins,
  update              => '1',
  download            => '1',
  upgrade             => '1',
  autoclean           => '7',
}
```

Comment: how do I set origins and what do I set them to?

Comment: this answer directly answers your question. please ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you!  For future reference, the origins options are at the top of `/cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

Comment: How does `"${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates";` relate to `$::apt::params::origins,` ?  What do I actually have to set the values to?

Comment: the params.pp file defines different defaults depending on the distribution fact, and ultimately using that default. That's the value it will take unless you provide a value. In my case, I specify it in hiera and then include the parameterized class like this `class {'unattended_upgrades': origins => hiera_array('unattended_upgrades::params::origins'), } }`

Comment: @h0tw1r3: perhaps this "directly answers [the] question", but it does so tersely... in a way that I, as a puppet novice (but not-at-all noob with regards to *nix stuff more generally), find quite unhelpful.  Perhaps it's worth expanding the answer to be a little more helpful, instead of sending someone off to ask a new question -- because as I'm sure you know, it's more than just the original asker that will look to answers for help.  When I try this, I get an error.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, and I'll do my own research, but this speaks to the usefulness of a richer answer, IMHO.

Comment: @lindes additional detail would not be useful. After 7 years of code changes, including a new maintainer, the module in question is very different. The lack of verbosity to my answer is the only reason it is still relevant.

Comment: @h0tw1r3 Well, if the module has changed substantially, then perhaps either an update is in order, or a new answer needs to be written.  The fact remains that this answer didn't help me find a solution -- though I tried tweaking it in various ways, as per error messages received, I wasn't able to find an incantation that got me out of error state, let alone doing what I'd been hoping for.  If you're no longer in this space 7 years later, that's entirely fine.  The fact remains that the answer isn't useful to a modern reader (or at least it wasn't to me).  No hard feelings, just... yeah.

Comment: @lindes Feel free to update the answer or add your own, that's the beauty of SO. I don't imagine too many contributors go back and revise 7 year old answers with zero upvotes.

Comment: @h0tw1r3 Well, the thing is, _I don't know the answer_ ... otherwise, I'd just write an answer, and let it compete with yours. Or if it was a trivial fix, I would indeed do as you suggest, and edit yours.  But I never figured out how to do this, and I moved on to other things (abandoning puppet for the task at hand -- it was only really ever a test anyway).  So when you, months after my comment, responded with a statement that additional detail would not be useful, I thought I'd let you know why I disagreed.  Anyway, unless we can pivot this to something constructive, that's all I'll say here.